# Are there stronger Axioms of Constructibility that say when $L_\beta$ starts containing $V_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory

**Are there stronger alternative axioms to the axiom of constructibility that additionally tell us *an upper bound on how long it can take* for things in $V$ to appear in $L$?**

For example, let $\kappa \leftarrow \lambda$ denote ordinal exponentiation $\kappa^\lambda$.

$$ \small\textbf{STRAWMAN:}\;\; V_{\alpha} \subset L_{\omega \leftarrow \alpha} $$

I'm curious because I was reading about the differences between $V$ and $L$ and saw a handful of results on Wikipedia relating $V_\alpha$ and $L_\alpha$.

---

What follows is background, motivation, and my attempt to make sense of the material.

---

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4009228) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009217/is-bzc-inconsistent-with-reinhardt-cardinals), which is substantially more advanced than my background, and stumbled on the notion of a Silver indiscernible. I tried to look up what a Silver indiscernible is and ended up on [this page describing $0^\#$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp). That led me to this discussion of the [Gödel constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), which is different from the [von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) that I've seen before but don't understand deeply. I tried to understand what the difference between these things is, and noticed there's an alternate axiom, the [Axiom of Constructibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) that asserts their equality. That got me wondering if we can *consistently insist on bounds* for when things in $V$ appear in $L$ if we take the axiom of constructibility (and so a set in $V$ always appears in $L$ eventually).

---

A given "slice" of the von Neumann universe $V_\alpha$ is indexed by an ordinal $\alpha$.

$$ V_0 = \emptyset $$
$$ V_{\beta+1} = P(V_{\beta}) \;\; \text{if $\beta$ is an ordinal number} $$
$$ V_{\lambda} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_{\alpha} \;\; \text{if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal} $$

And the universe as a whole is the union of all such slices.

Gödel's construction is similar, but in the $\beta+1$ case, it only takes some of the subsets, not all of them.

$$ L_0 = \emptyset $$
$$ L_{\beta+1} = \text{Def}(L_\beta) \;\; \text{if $\beta$ is an ordinal number} $$
$$ L_{\lambda} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} L_{\alpha} \;\; \text{if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal} $$

Where $\text{Def}$ is defined as follows.

Let's define a three-argument version of $\text{Def}$ where $\Phi$ is a well-formed formula and $\vec{z}$ is a finite vector of sets.

$$ \text{Def}(X, \Phi, \vec{z}) = 1 \;\;\text{iff}\;\;\text{each element of $\vec{z}$ is in $X$ and $(X, \in)$ is a model of $\Phi(\vec{z})$ } $$

$$ \text{otherwise $\text{Def}(X, \Phi, \vec{z})$ is zero } $$

So, a triple of $X, \Phi, \vec{z}$ gets sent to one if and only if $(X, \in)$ is a model of $\Phi(\vec{z})$ and $\vec{z}$, considered as a set, is a subset of $X$.

We can then define the one-argument version of $\text{Def}$ as follows.

$$ y \in \text{Def}(X) \;\;\text{iff}\;\; \text{there exists a $\Phi$ and $\vec{z}$ so that $\vec{z}_0 = y$ and $\text{Def}(X, \Phi, \vec{z}) = 1$} $$

It's clear that $\text{Def}(X)$ is a subset of $X$ and thus each $L_\alpha$ is clearly a subset of the corresponding $V_\alpha$.

The axiom of constructibility asserts that $V = L$, but doesn't say anything about how *long we need to wait in $L$* to get an element that appears in $V_\alpha$.

I'm wondering if there are stronger axioms that do insist on a bound up front.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually already completely determined by $V=L$.  In particular, note that $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ for all infinite $\alpha$, while $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ (and this is equal to $\aleph_\alpha$ assuming $V=L$).  So, $V_{\omega+\alpha}$ cannot be contained in $L_\beta$ for any $\beta<\omega_\alpha$, simply for cardinality reasons.  Conversely, I claim that $V=L$ implies $V_{\omega+\alpha}\subseteq L_{\omega_\alpha}$.  You can prove this by induction on $\alpha$.  Limit steps are trivial; for successor steps, suppose $V_{\omega+\alpha}\subseteq L_{\omega_\alpha}$ and we wish to show that $V_{\omega+\alpha+1}\subseteq L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$.  Since $V_{\omega+\alpha+1}=P(V_{\omega_\alpha})$, this follows from the fact that all constructible subsets of $L_{\omega_\alpha}$ are contained in $L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$ (this is a consequence of Gödel's condensation lemma, by essentially the same argument as the proof that $V=L$ implies GCH).

So, $V=L$ implies that for every $\alpha$, the least $\beta$ such that $V_{\omega+\alpha}\subseteq L_\beta$ is $\beta=\omega_\alpha$.