# Power sets vs definable power sets in the minimal standard model of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, axioms

As noted in [this answer by Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4033524/52694), as well as [the Wikipedia page on the Constructible Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), we have that $L_\alpha$ is strictly smaller than $V_\alpha$ for any $\alpha > \omega$ unless $\alpha = \omega_\alpha$. This is apparently a general statement that is true in ZFC even if $V = L$.

I am somewhat curious how this works in the minimal standard model of ZFC, where the axiom of constructibility holds. Apparently, even *within* the model, we are supposed to be able to prove that $L^M_{\omega+1} \subsetneq V^M_{\omega+1}$, where $L^M$ and $V^M$ refer to the model's idea of what $L$ and $V$ are. That is, although the model (and even the metatheory) agree on what $L^M_{\omega}$ and $V^M_{\omega}$ are, the model will somehow think that the definable $M$-powerset of $V^M_{\omega}$ (and, I guess, of $\Bbb N$) is strictly smaller than its true $M$-powerset.

Thus, it would seem that the minimal standard model includes at least *some* undefinable sets, or at least, enough to make $\mathbf{Def}^M(\Bbb N)$ strictly smaller than $\mathbf{P}^M(\Bbb N)$ within the model.

I, on the other hand, had always envisioned the minimal standard model as basically this thing which pretends that the true powerset *is* the definable powerset. My reasoning: the first-order axiom schema of comprehension only requires definable subsets to exist, so the definable powerset would seem to be the "thinnest possible powerset" that satisfies these requirements. I figured we'd just iterate that in $V$-like fashion, pretending that this minimalist powerset is the true powerset, and keep going until we get, at some interesting countable ordinal, a model of ZFC. But really what I was envisioning is something like the statement $L^M_\alpha = V^M_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ in the model -- much stronger than $V=L$ -- but above we have that $L^M_{\omega+1} \subsetneq V^M_{\omega+1}$.

Questions:

1. Am I understanding all this correctly?
2. If this is really right, what are the elements that are in, for instance, the model's idea of $\mathbf{P}(\Bbb N)$ which are "missing" from $\mathbf{Def}(\Bbb N)$?
3. In general, what does the minimal standard model think that powersets are? That is, if the model thinks the "true powerset" of $V^M_\omega$ is strictly larger than the "definable powerset" of it, then the model's "true powerset" equals the set of definable subsets of $V^M_\omega$, plus _____?

Comment: With regards to your first paragraph, where does it say that in either source? If V=L, then there are a proper class of $\kappa$ at which $V_\kappa=L_\kappa$ (namely, any $\beth$ fixed point).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2546720/28111.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add that clarification; I was mostly focused on successor ordinals (e.g. which are power sets of something). I've added that although it doesn't seem to affect the meat of the question being asked.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Yeah, I gathered that was tangential to the question. (And I wasn't the downvoter here... apologies if my brusque correction somehow contributed to that.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Having forgotten whatever paltry amount I may have once learned about this subject, it seems like an easy corollary of what I wrote below is that there are no new constructible reals added between $\omega_1^M$ and $Ord(M)$, where $M$ is the minimal model. Do I have that right?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yup, that's condensation (relativized to $M$) + the absoluteness of the $L$-hierarchy. Building $L$ within $M$ looks just like building $L$ within $V$ up to $Ord(M)$ (and this is true for all transitive models $M$, not just the minimal one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to understand why $V_{\omega+1}\ne L_{\omega+1}$ in $L$ before thinking about the minimal model, because the situation in the minimal model is not really any different.

The basic results are that for any ordinal $\alpha,$ $L_\alpha^L = L_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha^L = V_\alpha\cap L$ and for any $x\in L,$ $P^L(x) = P(x)\cap L.$ So, $V_{\omega+1}^L$ is all the constructible subsets of $V_\omega$ whereas $L_{\omega+1}^L$ are all of the subsets of $V_{\omega}$ that are definable with parameters in $V_\omega.$ These can't be the same, just on cardinality grounds: the former manifestly has cardinality continuum in $L$ whereas the latter is countable since the number of definitions with parameters are countable.

What's "missing" from $L_{\omega+1}$ is all the subsets of $V_\omega$ that will be added to the constructible hierarchy at later stages, e.g. there may be some subset of $V_\omega$ that is definable with parameters in $L_{\omega+5}$ that wasn't definable with parameters in $L_{\omega+n}$ for $n=0$ through $4.$

In the minimal model the idea is the same. The minimal model is $L_\xi$ for some countable ordinal $\xi,$ and for $\alpha<\xi,$ $L_\alpha^M=L_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha^M = V_\alpha\cap M$ and for any $x\in M,$ $P^M(x)= P(x)\cap M.$ In the minimal model, $L_{\omega+1}$ is exactly the same thing it was in $L$ (or in $V$ for that matter). $V_{\omega+1}^M$ isn't all constructible subsets of $V_\omega,$ but rather it's all subsets of $V_\omega$ with constructibility rank less than $\xi.$

So it's the same thing... what's "missing" from $L_{\omega+1}^M$ is all the subsets of $V_\omega$ that are constructible at some higher rank. There are fewer higher ranks that can contribute now since we cut off at $\xi$ (actually, per Godel's results, only ranks up to $\omega_1^M<\xi$ contribute) but that doesn't really make a difference for the question.

Comment: Aha! This is way subtler than I thought. Ok, I get it now. What do you mean by "actually, per Godel's results, only ranks up to $ω^M_1 < ξ$ contribute"?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The proof that CH holds in $L$ is done by showing every constructible real (or equivalently constructible subset of $V_\omega$) appears in $L_{\omega_1^L}$, i.e. there are no new reals added after $\omega_1^L.$ Then since $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|,$ we have $|P(\omega)|\le \aleph_1$ in $L$. My remark is just this relativized to $M.$ (By "contribute" I mean there are new subsets added at that rank... though I should have said "*can* contribute" since some. but not all of them do.)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the notation $L_{\omega_1^L}$: do you mean that $\omega_1^L$ is different in $L$ from $\omega_1$ in $V$, in general? Because I thought that $L$, as an inner model of $V$, had the same ordinals as $V$.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Same ordinals, possibly different *cardinals*. The thing $L$ thinks is $\omega_1$ might actually (= in $V$) be countable.